# What definition of now is used in our stellar neighbourhood?

Tags: general-relativity, time, astronomy, conventions, milky-way

Within General Relativity the idea of simultaneity is fairly arbitrary, every coordinate system has one. Which one corresponds to my personal local sense of now appears indefinable in any objective sense. One can define something a bit like a moment in time given a time-like Killing field and a (hyper) surface orthogonal to it. But, the rub is to define the Killing field over a region of spacetime in the practical sense. Of our local stellar neighborhood - perhaps a few hundred light years in diameter - we make 3D maps saying where everything is. But where everything is at one moment of time requires the definition of one moment of time.

What definition do we use in practice for one moment of time?

Note: the motive behind my question is to find out how the failure of simultaneity interacts with our instinctive experience of time in, let's call it, a Galilean mode. Even if spacetime near the Earth is sufficiently flat to be Galilean to the accuracy of our experiments, we are still setting up a Galilean frame by some implicit means. The details of that would be an answer in the intended spirit of the question. I might need to do more research myself before anyone could answer the question in that spirit. It would definitely disappoint me to discover that no one has even considered the problem.

Comment: Hi Ponder Stibbons. Did you try to do a back-of-an-envelope-calculation of the effect?

Comment: @Qmechanic AFAIK, the fastest star seen is not near here and is said to be traveling at 8% of c. At that level the gamma factor gives a deviation of about 0.3% by a quick calculation. But, I am less familiar with how much this would affect specific measurements we are interested in. Should I extend the question to be the whole galaxy instead of just the stellar neighborhood? The real issue on my mind would be how might you do it, assuming it did become significant. So, proving that the effect was too small would force me to change the question.

Comment: For precision work *inside* the Solar System, we use TDB or [TCB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_Coordinate_Time). For details of the conversion between Earth-based [TAI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Atomic_Time) and TDB see section 2.3 of [The JPL Planetary and Lunar Ephemerides DE440 and DE441](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.3847/1538-3881/abd414), Ryan S. Park et al (2021).

Comment: @PM2Ring That looks more like what I was looking for thanks.

Comment: No worries. We can't do that sort of thing outside the Solar System because (as John D says) we simply don't know the distances (or masses) to high precision, so we can't calculate the gravitational potentials in our stellar neighbourhood to the precision where relativistic corrections are necessary. FWIW, I just made a rough plot of the annual variation in time dilation on Earth due to the Sun's gravitational potential (ignoring SR dilation due to velocity). The horizontal axis is true anomaly (in radians), which is roughly proportional to time.

Comment: [Gravitational time dilation plot in Sage](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJx9UcFu1EAMvUfKP1jtYZMlTZOFJewhR8qRiuWGEHInE2I6kwkep134epw0XDgwGmnk8fPzs981nINDhsAPJPCd8YkEhcKIDoS8hY7cGqdJz8GDR5lcEEcPpZB5tAzkp8ACZ4PKcxdYEWJZ4V6ghcP-yz-ZbI72Y99HK-0dumjzr2nyhJztZNjlaZIm1_AeWYZNkjXGjsJkSH6liTXKWZVV_bapq8PhBX62nm48_ggMeKFYwKNPE1RgXVbrqWvYQ_3mdDw175qqbLayedxF1T08I_-OZiDXAWNH88bAcdFfno6vD8eqaraqTysCUC_082iW3UDoQXi2gGPw6FTnpKWoTbMabnSEvTU6mpJnMuSamuB2Sb3SlIJMiMv_NvyH_3kgXXZZCOJPlpVbRd7CZS29X4jVm0xBW6u8AH0KqAo1YiINe0Zv288qtlC3qXM02therdu7KmDx9Fv_16pWPVTq-zIO4TnL_wDfcqfD&lang=sage)

Answer (score 2):

When we report the time of an observed event outside the solar system, we generally use the time of arrival of the news (carried by light, gravitational waves, neutrinos, ...) at Earth. If we're really fussy, we report the inferred time of arrival of the news at the solar system barycenter. We can't correct accurately for distance, since we generally don't know the distance well enough.

Answer (score 0):

Even at the galactic scale things don't move much. It's all entirely classical and there is no need to drag general relativity into it. The diameter of the Milky Way is approx. 100,000 light years but it takes almost 200 million years for a single rotation. That's a scale separation of three orders of magnitude.

The proper motion of a typical star in the night sky is 0.1 seconds of arc per year. That means most stars take on the order of 18,000 years to move by a full moon diameter. Except for a few very fast ones like Barnard's star (which is not visible to the naked eye) it's all very slow out there. There would have been very few obvious changes during the entire written history of mankind in the heavens above.

Your moment of time is here and now. You really don't have to care what happens 300 light years away "at this moment". You have no influence over it and it doesn't have any influence over you. Truthfully, relativity is the universe's way to separate concerns.

Comment: Your last paragraph sounds like philosophy. But, I guess your answer is that they assume Newtonian space time as they don't make any measurements accurate enough to matter. Although that does not sound like it is obviously correct. For example, the measurement of the precession of mercury happens right here in our own solar system.

Comment: @PonderStibbons It was more of a joke. I am fully aware that there is no sensible way of saying "what is happening on Alpha Centauri Prime right now" since it is observer dependent. In relativity "here is now" and "elsewhere is at some other time, but it's not even a unique time". I do share some of your discomfort with the weird event structure of spacetime. I could never completely wrap my head around it, either.

Comment: This is partly related to an attempt to really get my head around it.